# Why can't i exit from shellcode with a syscall?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, shellcode

I try to make a Programm where you put in some assembled assembly in hex and run it.
With simple instructions like `int3` it works, but when I try to exit from the programm with a syscall it doesnt work.
I assembled it with `rasm2`

```
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 12
int 0x80
```

and then put it as an argument `./Programm b801000000bb0c000000cd80 1`
but i get a segfault.

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

char *base16dec(char *b16str) {
  size_t stingrlength = strlen(b16str);
  char *decodedstr = malloc(stingrlength / 2);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < stingrlength; i += 2) {
    u_int8_t num = 0;
    char stringIn[3];
    stringIn[0] = b16str[i];
    stringIn[1] = b16str[i+1];
    stringIn[2] = 0;
    sscanf(stringIn, "%hhx", &num);
    decodedstr[i/2] = (char) num;
  }
  return decodedstr;
}
```

this decodes the hex string

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *dirstr = "XXXXXX";
  char dir[7];
  strcpy(dir, dirstr);
  int fd = mkstemp(dir);
  if (fd == -1) {
    dirstr = "/tmp/XXXXXX";
    char dir[12];
    strcpy(dir, dirstr);
    fd = mkstemp(dir);
  }
  unlink(dir);
```

this creates the tmp file where the assembly is stored

```c
  char *stringIn;
  if (argc == 2) {
    stringIn = malloc(strlen(argv[1]));
    strcpy(stringIn, argv[1]);
  } else if (argc == 3) {
    u_int8_t num = 0;
    sscanf(argv[2], "%hhu", &num);
    if (num == 1) {
      char *done = base16dec(argv[1]);
      stringIn = malloc(strlen(done));
      strcpy(stringIn, done);
    } else {
      stringIn = malloc(strlen(argv[1]));
      strcpy(stringIn, argv[1]);
    }
  } else {
    stringIn = malloc(1024);
    scanf("%s", stringIn);
    char *done = base16dec(stringIn);
    stringIn = malloc(strlen(done));
    strcpy(stringIn, done);
  }
```

this parses and copies the input to `stringIn`

```c
  ftruncate(fd, strlen(stringIn));
  u_int8_t *code = mmap(NULL, strlen(stringIn), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE , fd, 0);
```

this expands the tmp file and makes it executable and creates a pointer to it named `code`

```c
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    code[i] = (u_int8_t) stringIn[i];
  }
```

this copies the assembly bytes into `code`

```c
  #if __x86_64__
  __asm__(
    "mov %0, %%rbx\n"
    "jmp *%%rbx"
    :
    : "g" (code)
    : "memory"
  );
  #elif __i386__
  __asm__(
    "mov %0, %%ebx\n"
    "jmp *%%ebx"
    :
    : "r" (code)
  );
  #else
  #endif
```

this jumps to the the assembly

```c
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

I can't debug the shellcode using gdb

I use 64bit Linux Mint

***I tried to copy `0` using `strcpy`***

Comment: at&t uses `$` prefix for immediates. You want `mov $1, %eax` and `mov $12, %ebx`.

Comment: Which instruction does your code segfault on?  Did all your system calls return success?  Did you use `strace` to make sure all the system calls resulted in success?  [edit] to make this a [MCVE]. (And BTW, a tmp file seems like massive overkill.  Just `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` an executable + writeable page.  Also, if you're using x86-64 on WSL on Windows, 32-bit `int 0x80` system calls don't work, only the 64-bit `syscall` ABI.

Comment: Without a tmp file I get a segfault. ```mmap(NULL, strlen(stringIn), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_ANONYMOUS , -1, 0);```

Comment: _"I can't debug the shellcode using gdb"_ - why not? Anyway using `"g" (code)` is a very bad idea. No telling what the compiler will use there. Why not just use a function pointer?

Comment: How can I do that? I tried void `(*code_ptr)(void) = code;` but I got an error `error: initialization from incompatible pointer type`

Comment: @MaxSilvester: cast to `(void*)` because in C you can assign that to anything, or cast to pointer-to-function with `(void (*)(void))code`.  Of course a `char*` can't implicitly convert to a function pointer, the compiler is there to protect you from that just like from assigning a `float *` to an `int*` variable without a cast.  Use `void*` if you want the compiler to stay out of the way.

Comment: You still have to use `MAP_PRIVATE` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, i.e. `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS`.  When you passed *just* `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, `mmap` returned `-1` with errno=EINVAL or something similar.  **Use `strace`** to see what glibc malloc and/or CRT startup code does, and to see what errors your own system calls fail with.  `strace` is the quick and dirty replacement for writing code that checks for errors, in toy experiments like this.  Doing one or the other is necessary to rule out silly mistakes like that.

Comment: When I try to disassemble the shellcode to see if it's right it says `(gdb) disassemble`
`No function contains program counter for selected frame.`

Comment: I tried `void *code_void_ptr = code;``void (*code_ptr)(void) = code_void_ptr;` but I got an error again `error: ISO C forbids initialization between function pointer and ‘void *’`

Comment: Use something like `x/10i 0xwhatever` to disassemble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a shellcode you can't have null bytes. In your code you have 2 movs with immediates that are padded to 32-bits

```
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 12
```

Which encodes as B801**000000**BB0C**000000**, when C hits the null bytes it thinks the string has ended so it only ends up copying part of the instruction and then it executes garbage.

Instead you'll need to use:

```
xor eax, eax
inc eax
xor ebx, ebx
mov bl, 12
```

This will provide the values you want for your system call and does not encode as any null bytes.